# RestTemplate PATCH request

Tags: json, spring, resttemplate

I have the following definition for PersonDTO:

```
public class PersonDTO
{
    private String id
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String maritalStatus;
}
```

Here is a sample record :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "maritalStatus": "married"
}
```

Now, John Doe gets divorced. So I need to send a PATCH request to this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/people/1
```

With the following request body:

```
{
    "maritalStatus": "divorced"
}
```

I cannot figure out how to do it. Here is what I tried so far:

```
// Create Person
PersonDTO person = new PersonDTO();
person.setMaritalStatus("Divorced");

// Create HttpEntity
final HttpEntity<ObjectNode> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(person);

// Create URL (for eg: localhost:8080/people/1)
final URI url = buildUri(id);

ResponseEntity<Void> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PATCH, requestEntity, Void.class);
```

Here are the problems with the above:

1) As I am setting only MaritalStatus, the other fields would all be null. So if I print out the request, it will look like this:

```
{
    "id": null,
    "firstName": "null",
    "lastName": "null",
    "maritalStatus": "married" // I only need to update this field.
}
```

Does that mean that I have to a GET before I do a PATCH?

2) I am getting the following stack trace:

```
08:48:52.717 ERROR c.n.d.t.s.PersonServiceImpl - Unexpected Exception  : 
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PATCH request for "http://localhost:8080/people/1":Invalid HTTP method: PATCH; nested exception is java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:580) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:545) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:466) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sp.restclientexample..service.PersonServiceImpl.doPatch(PersonServiceImpl.java:75) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sp.restclientexample..service.PatchTitle.itDoPatch(PatchTitle.java:53) [test-classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:440) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:517) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.prepareConnection(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:209) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:138) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor.createRequest(HttpAccessor.java:76) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:565) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Appreciate any pointers from folks who have written client applications to consume a Restful webservice using Spring's RestTemplate.

For completeness, let me also state that we use SpringDataRest for our backend restful webservices.

SGB

Comment: which version of spring is this?

Comment: here is the **WHY** you have to include `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` : The standard JDK HTTP library does not support HTTP PATCH. You need to use the Apache HttpComponents or OkHttp request factory [doc link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#patchForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I solved this problem just adding a new HttpRequestFactory to my restTemplate instance. Like this

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
requestFactory.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);

restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
```

For TestRestTemplate, add

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

@Before
public void setup() {
    restTemplate.getRestTemplate().setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
}
```

PS: You will need add httpClient component in your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: To save some lines you can do the RestTemplate initialisation in one line `new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory())`

Comment: @adebasi Do you know why this is required?

Comment: I think with "this" you mean the fact that you have to set the `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`. This commment (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7985?focusedCommentId=80924&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-80924) answers your question.

Comment: Still a problem in 2021, WTF. But thanks for your solution :)

Comment: This answer could be improved significantly by including context around why this is required and/or why it is a "fix".

Comment: Using Spring Boot 3, I had to use this dependency instead `org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2.1`

Comment: Solution for spring boot 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76773258/2674303

Comment: @Taoufik Mohdit why haven't you created ans answer=). You would save 4 hours of my life

Comment: @gstackoverflow Sorry this took you so long :-). At the time, I thought the dependency adjustment didn't warrant a separate answer

Answer (score 11):

For me solved by adding below line:

```
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

Comment: Worked for me as well. Can anyone please explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 9):

For cases where `RestTemplate` is built from a `RestTemplateBuilder`, constructor for the custom RestClient can be written as,

```
public PersonRestClient(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
  this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()).build();
}
```

Also, the `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient` dependency needs to added to pom.

Comment: for springboot 2 its `.requestFactory(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.class)`

Comment: @DannyK Thanks for pointing out Spring boot 2 way of configuring it.

Comment: If you use spring-boot v2.3, then its configured automatically, if you add the dependency to your project.

Comment: Do you still need to add the dependency if it comes transitively?  I'm asking this because I do have it in my classpath, but not declared in my pom.

Answer (score 7):

I have added the below code in the java file. It worked for me.

```
String url="Your API URL";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new 
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));    
HttpHeaders reqHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
reqHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestJson, reqHeaders);
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity=restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PATCH, 
requestEntity, String.class);
```

Also, need to add the below dependency in the pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Solution** for spring boot 3:

I faced the same issue for my spring boot 3 but neither of solution helped me.

Eventually I realized that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29803488/2674303) is working, but library should be

```
  Implementation("org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2.1")
```

or even (to allow spring boot choose the version it likes)

**Preferred option:**

```
Implementation("org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5")
```

instead of:

```
implementation("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1")
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a generic method to do this when there are linked resources involved:

```
public void patch(M theEntity, Integer entityId, String linkName, URI linkUri) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = getObjectMapperWithHalModule();
    ObjectNode linkedNode = (ObjectNode) objectMapper.valueToTree(theEntity);
    linkedNode.put(linkName, linkUri.getPath());

    HttpEntity<ObjectNode> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(linkedNode);

    restTemplate.exchange(uri + "/" + entityId, HttpMethod.PATCH, requestEntity, Void.class);
}

private ObjectMapper getObjectMapperWithHalModule() {
    if(objectMapperHal == null) {
        objectMapperHal = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapperHal.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapperHal.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
    }

    return objectMapperHal;
}
```

Feel free to look at an implementation of this example at [my full jal+json implementation](https://github.com/gusops/ride-keeper)

Answer (score 1):

`WebClient` offers a modern alternative to the `RestTemplate` with efficient support for both sync and async, as well as streaming scenarios. You can implement this with WebClient.

Configure `WebClient`

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
}
```

Then you can call method

```html
//Constructor Injection 
public YourClassName(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
    this.webClientBuilder = webClientBuilder;
}

webClientBuilder.build()
      .patch()
      .uri("http://localhost:8081/api/v1/customers/{id}", id)
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(Void.class)
      .block();
```

Dependency for pom.xml

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an older spring version than 3.1.0, then you don't have the PATCH method in the HttpMethods. You can still use HttpClient from apache. Here is a short example on how I did it:

```
    try {

        //This is just to avoid ssl hostname verification and to trust all, you can use simple Http client also
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLContext(new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, TrustAllStrategy.INSTANCE).build())
                .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE).build();

        HttpPatch request = new HttpPatch(REST_SERVICE_URL);
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(JSON.toJSONString(payload), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        request.setEntity(params);
        request.addHeader(org.apache.http.HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        //You can use other authorization method, like user credentials
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, OAuth2AccessToken.BEARER_TYPE + " " + accessToken);
        HttpResponse response =     httpClient.execute(request);            

        String statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle exception here
    }
```

The equivalent of this, with RestTemplate would be:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("Authorization", OAuth2AccessToken.BEARER_TYPE + " " + accessToken);
    final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(JSON.toJSONString(payload), headers);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    try {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(REST_SERVICE_URL, HttpMethod.PATCH, entity, String.class);
        String statusCode =  response.getStatusCode();
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        // handle exception here
    }
```

Also, make sure the payload only contains the values you need to change, and make sure you are sending the request to the right URL. (this can be in some cases something ending like /api/guest/{id} )

Answer (score 0):

this will work if verified answer dose works

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance someone is looking at this in or after 2023

The httpClient library has been moved to httpclient5

```
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2.1'
```

Latest version can be found here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.client5/httpclient5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).