# How do I implement a PATCH executed via RestTemplate?

Tags: java, rest, junit, resttemplate, http-patch

I am coding JUnit tests, calling my application via `RestTemplate`. I have successfully implemented GETs, POSTs, and PUTs, but can not get a PATCH to run (though it works when a client sends in the URL). A POST, for example, runs with this code:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
    ProductModel postModel = restTemplate.postForObject(TestBase.URL + URL, pModel, ProductModel.class);
```

But when I tried to call restTemplate.patchForObject() - which I found online - STS returns an error saying that function is not defined. I thus used this:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
    ResponseEntity<MessageModel> retval = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/products/batchUpdateProductPositions", 
            HttpMethod.PATCH, new HttpEntity<ProductPositionListModel>(pps), MessageModel.class);
```

Which compiles, but gives me an error:

```
I/O Error on PATCH request for "http://localhost:8080/products/batchUpdateProductPositions": Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
```

In the application, I have the operation defined in a Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/batchUpdateProductPositions", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
public MessageModel batchUpdatePosition(
        @RequestBody ProductPositionListModel productPositionList)
        throws Exception {
    try {
        return productService.batchUpdatePosition(productPositionList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
```

I put a breakpoint on the return statement inside the 'try' block, but it never tripped when I ran it under debug.

Can anyone tell me where I tripped up?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447382/resttemplate-patch-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered a solution that stays consistent with the rest of the JUnit code. Using postForObject(), you can pass in the HTTP method you need in this case:

```
    MessageModel pModel = restTemplate.postForObject(TestBase.URL + URL + "/batchUpdateProductPositions?_method=patch", 
            pps, MessageModel.class);
```

This runs correctly. Couldn't say if there are side effects I'm not noticing.

Comment: And [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19618?attachmentViewMode=list#issuecomment-453449391) is the explanation.

Answer (score 8):

By default `RestTemplate` uses standard JDK `HttpURLConnection` HTTP client to make requests. This client does not support `PATCH` method. You can configure `RestTemplate` to use some other HTTP client via client factory, like `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` or `OkHttpClientHttpRequestFactory`.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
RestTemplate template= new RestTemplate();
template.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client));
```

You will also need to add proper dependencies, something like `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:$version` in case HTTP Components client.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, for execution of a PATCH request using RestTemplate:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
httpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
httpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(timeout);

restTemplate.setRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory);
```

Now use this restTemplate with exchange().

Required Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
//...
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory())

//Now make the PATCH call using Exchange
ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> response = rest.exchange(api, HttpMethod.PATCH, request, responseType);
```

Do not forget to add this to your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Solution

```
MessageModel pModel = restTemplate.postForObject(TestBase.URL + URL + "/batchUpdateProductPositions?_method=patch",pps, MessageModel.class);
```

Is useful if you are using a Post Method(`@PostMapping`), If you would like to use Patch Method(`@PatchMapping`), Try this:

```
restTemplate.patchForObject("http://localhost:8080/products/batchUpdateProductPositions", requestEntity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

`WebClient` offers a modern alternative to the `RestTemplate` with efficient support for both sync and async, as well as streaming scenarios. You can implement this with WebClient.

Configure `WebClient`

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
}
```

Then you can call method

```
//Constructor Injection 
public YourClassName(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
   this.webClientBuilder = webClientBuilder;
}

MessageModel response = webClientBuilder.build()
                .patch()
                .uri("http://localhost:8080/products/batchUpdateProductPositions")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(MessageModel.class)
                .block();
```

Dependency for pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to overcome this issue,

Add the below dependency in `pom.xml`,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
```

Import `CloseableHttpClient`, and `HttpClients` from the above dependency's jar file.

To make `HTTP Patch` request using `RestTemplate`, below configurations are mandatory, for other `HTTP` calls you may ignore it.

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    LOGGER.info("restTemplate Bean has bean created");
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

In the request class use the below code,

```
ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PATCH,  requestEntity, Object.class);
```