# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, resttemplate, spring-boot-3

To address the same issue as here [RestTemplate PATCH request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447382/resttemplate-patch-request) in my spring-boot 3 application

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PATCH request for "http://localhost:8080/people/1":Invalid HTTP method: PATCH; nested exception is java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
```

I do things similar as in accepted response:

```
@Configuration
class TestRestTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    fun testRestTemplate(restTemplateBuilder: RestTemplateBuilder): TestRestTemplate {
        val testRestTemplate = TestRestTemplate(restTemplateBuilder, null, null, null)
        testRestTemplate.restTemplate.requestFactory = HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()
        return testRestTemplate
    }
}
```

Also I have dependency:

```
implementation("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.14")
```

But when I start test I see an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient
```

But If I try to find this class in my IDE I am able to do it:

[image]

I tried to execute command `gradle clean` but no luck. I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is replace

```
implementation("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.14")
```

with

```
Implementation("org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5")
```

Comment: The real solution is to let Spring Boot manage your dependencies instead of doing it manually.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel could you be a bit more specific please ?

Comment: You're not doing things according to how Spring Boot should be used, if you'd let Spring Boot manage the dependencies, it would either have imported the correct dependencies automatically or you wouldn't have needed to specify the version of dependencies which Spring Boot manages but does not depend on by default.

Comment: What should I do to let Spring Boot manage my dependencies ? specifically this one

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.2/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Actually I have `plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.21"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
`

Comment: 1. Tried to remove
`testImplementation("org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2.1")`

But no luck - ClassNotFoundException

Comment: 2. Without version also works

` testImplementation("org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5")`

Comment: The linked document says you should use `id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.2'`...

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel oh, it is so fresh. let me try

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel for my 3.1.0 - result is the same

Comment: Which starters do you have specified?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel
`   implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
`

Comment: Turns out I was wrong specifically about Apache HTTP client being pulled in automatically... my apologies. Spring will use it if it is on the classpath, but otherwise fallback to HttpUrlConnection. But in any case, specifying versionless should always be preferred for dependencies managed by Spring Boot (and Apache HTTP client is)

Comment: Thank you for your report.  I've removed version. Looks like it improved the answer.